# "Next" Button grayed out when Manually Partitioning during install

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, software-installation, 23.04

Currently attempting to install Ubuntu 23.04 dual-booted with a PC running Windows 11. Additionally, the PC has two drives: the C, where Windows is running, and the D, where I want my Ubuntu to run. Additionally, I currently already have partitions set up, along with an EFI Partition already set on my D: Drive (I already have an Arch-based Linux Distro, which I'm attempting to overwrite)

The issue that occurs is when I go to manual partition, it lets me select my EFI Disk as well as the partition where I want Ubuntu to run on, but after doing so, the "Next" button gets grayed out, and I am unable to click it which is halting the install process. I have attached images of this issue to this post.

[image: The Installer in the Manual Partitioning Screen]

Comment: Did you assign the use of sda3 as / (root)?  Maybe you'll need a root to proceed.

Comment: How exactly could I assign it as / ?

Comment: Select the sda3 line, click the change button, then under one of the dropdowns, you have a choice of how to use it, and "/" is probably the first in the list.

Answer (score 4):

Turns out it was a simple mistake.

You have the click on the partition that you want to use, aka sda3, then click change and then assign it to "/" which is root. Then it works.

The only thing that the checkmark does is format the partition, but it's not setting it as any ubuntu filesystem.